# Detecting bounded regions in JavaScript

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, object-detection

I have an image of a crossword , and I would like to find the x,y coordinates of every valid square and the number associated with it, then I would feed it into [crossword.js](https://github.com/dwmkerr/crosswords-js).

Here are some sample crosswords:

[image: crossword image]

[image: crossword image]

I'm intending on using JavaScript so I can eventually make a browser extension or stackapp.

I've found *[numerous](https://flatlogic.com/blog/12-javascript-image-manipulation-libraries-for-your-next-web-app/)* image processing libraries for JavaScript, but the vast majority seem focused on transformation of the image, not edge or boundary detection.

Even when I find [edge detection programs](https://codepen.io/taylorcoffelt/pen/EsCcr), they seem focused on fuzzy objects, or [real world objects](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2021/01/custom-object-detection-in-browser.html).

I've tried OCR but it looks like the free service I found is [a ways off from working](https://forum.ui.vision/t/table-mode-for-crossword-grids/9208?u=pureferret).

It's made me think I'm looking for the wrong processing algorithm.

Is there a term for the sort of image processing I need to do? Is it possible with JavaScript?

Comment: I think this depends a lot on the variability of the set of images you want to accurately process. If they always follow exactly the same general pattern, only having variable number of squares and numbers inside each box, the problem should be trivial. If you want to generalize to odd shapes, different fonts, embedded photos that should be excluded, the complexity depends on that variability.

Comment: @KnutInge the grid would change, but should always look similar. The font is also going to be more or less the same? I don't know why a crossword would have an embedded image. Would a few more samples help?

Comment: Example of crossword with embedded image: https://www.gratiskryssord.no/content/images/2019/05/dagens-kryssord-1-januar-2019.jpg

Comment: @KnutInge thats not a crossword. Or at least not one I'm intending on catering for. That's more often called an [arrowword](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arrowword)